# MySQL Cursor Error Unknown Variable

Tags: mysql, cursor

I created a store procedure to do some insertions, fetch the records of a table and insert it into another table. For that I used cursor (my first use of cursor).
My script below:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tenant_creation`(
  IN admin_id int, tenant_name varchar(50),tenant_url varchar(50),
  tenant_email varchar(50),tenant_phone varchar(50),first_name varchar(50),
last_name varchar(50),plan_id varchar(50),IN is_available tinyint
)
BEGIN

  DECLARE exit handler for sqlexception
   BEGIN
   ROLLBACK;
  END;

DECLARE exit handler for sqlwarning
  BEGIN
   ROLLBACK;
  END;

 BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

#insert Tenant details
Insert into tenant(admin_id,tenant_name,tenant_url,tenant_email,tenant_phone,first_name,last_name,plan_id,  is_available) 
values(admin_id,tenant_name,tenant_url,tenant_email,tenant_phone,first_name,last_name,plan_id,is_available);

SET @tenant_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

#create Administrator Group
Insert into user_group(tenant_id,user_group_name,description) 
values(@tenant_id,"Administrator","Default Administrator's Group");

SET @group_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

#Create Default Tenan Admin User
Insert into users(tenant_id,username,`password`,firstname,lastname,email) 
values(@tenant_id,"Administrator","$2y$10$AxTjqOxYk6atjDSO2Q4iQOprSvYMnR/jAboqfDYkvC1IG43Rwknw6","Default","Default",tenant_email);

#Attach the user to the group
Set @user_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

Insert into user_group_relationship(tenant_id,user_group_id,user_id)
values(@tenant_id,@group_id,@user_id);

#create Admin profile
insert into profile(tenant_id,profile_name,description)
values(@tenant_id,"Administrator","Administrator Profile");

#Attach the Admin group to the profile
Set @profile_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();

Insert into profile_group_relationship(tenant_id,group_id,profile_id)
values(@tenant_id,@group_id,@profile_id);

 END;

 BEGIN

#bind the profile to the available screens
 #1 fetch all the modules in system
 DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR Select system_screen.screen_id,system_screen.screen_name,module_screen_relationship.module_id
     from system_screen 
     join module_screen_relationship
     on module_screen_relationship.screen_id = system_screen.screen_id;

     begin
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

        OPEN cur;
        read_loop: LOOP

            #Fetch one record from CURSOR and set to some variable(If not found then done will be set to 1 by continue handler)
            FETCH cur INTO c_screen_id,c_screen_name,c_module_id;  
            #If done set to 1 then exit the loop else continue
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;  
            END IF;

            Insert into profile_screen_relationship(tenant_id,profile_id,screen_id,module_id,access_level) 
            values(@tenant_id,@profile_id,c_screen_id,c_module_id,4);

        END LOOP read_loop;
        #Closing the cursor
        CLOSE cur; 
    End;

     COMMIT;
   END;
END
```

but I only got "Error 1327: Undeclared variable: c_screen_id".

What do you think I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have to declare the variables at the beggining as the official documentation shows:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html

```
DECLARE a CHAR(16);
DECLARE b, c INT;
```

....

```
FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
FETCH cur2 INTO c;
```